# How do I --debug-init on Android?

Tags: android

I'm starting Emacs like this:

```
adb shell am start -n org.gnu.emacs/org.gnu.emacs.EmacsActivity
```

, but run into some problems that I need to debug.

If I try to pass "--debug-init"

```
adb shell am start -n org.gnu.emacs/org.gnu.emacs.EmacsActivity --es ARGS "--debug-init"
```

it says:

```
Starting: Intent { cmp=org.gnu.emacs/.EmacsActivity (has extras) }
```

, but it doesn't start Emacs with --debug-init.

Is there some other way I should pass this parameter?

Does Emacs on Android even support any parameters. Where is the source code for Emacs on Android?

If it doesn't support parameters, is there any way to pass this in the init file?;)

Comment: This is a question about how to use adb. Surely it has a way to pass arguments to the program you are asking it to run. Consult the documentation or ask on an android forum instead.